# Gcovr errors under Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, gcov, gcovr

I'm trying to generate a HTML file of results of a C program using Gcovr.
I've installed gcov (via MinGW), Python, easy_stall and gcovr.
Added the `C:\MinGW\bin`, `C:\Python33` and `C:\Python\Scripts` to the Windows PATH.

Now the problems I'm having (in Windows commandline):

**1. gcovr command**

gcovr cannot be found/executed from any directory until executed from `c:\Python33\Scripts` with the `python gcovr` command.

Temp fix, rename `gcovr` to `gcovr.py`? But this doesn't sound as the right solution.

**2. Executing gcovr**

No results when I call:

```
c:\Python33\Scripts>python gcovr -r "d:\somepath\Debug"
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          0       0    --%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But gcov gives proper results.

```
D:\somepath\Debug>gcov some_file.gcda
File '../some_file.c'
Lines executed:21.43% of 14
Creating 'some_file.c.gcov'
```

What do I need to do to get proper results?

Comment: I have the same problem - were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the same command without the `-r` option, that is:

`c:\Python33\Scripts>python gcovr "d:\somepath\Debug"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did solve it with following approach.

Go to root (main) directory of your project.

To generate output in Tabular format,
in command prompt, Give the command to generate coverage in

1) **Tabular format**

```
     "python C:\Python27\Scripts\gcovr -r . --object-directory <path to *.gcno *.gcda file>"
```

2) **XML format**

```
   "python C:\Python27\Scripts\gcovr -r . --object-directory <path to *.gcno *.gcda file> -x -o <desired_name.xml>"
```

3) **HTML format**

```
   "python C:\Python27\Scripts\gcovr -r . --object-directory <path to *.gcno *.gcda file> –-html -o <desired_name.html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This post may resolve your issue.

[GCOVR giving empty results zero percent in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875615/gcovr-giving-empty-results-zero-percent-in-mac/38917149)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

The problem is that your source file is not "below" the root folder and by default gcovr will filter it.

If you call

```
python gcovr -r "d:\somepath\Debug" --verbose
```

you will notice the line

```
Filtering coverage data for file ../some_file.c
```

An easy fix is to add a filter option:

```
python gcovr -r "d:\somepath\Debug" --verbose -f .*
```

From gcovr help:

> -f FILTER, --filter=FILTER
>                           Keep only the data files that match this regular
>                           expression

What gcovr documentation fail to mention is that if you do not provide a filter it will use the root path as default filter.

Hope it will help someone.